# nginx reverse proxy unexpected redirect

Tags: http, nginx, networking, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx running as a reverse proxy with configuration /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/10.0.0.1.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name 10.0.0.1;

    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

and the blog service running on 127.0.0.1:8080.

When i query http://localhost/blog/ on the machine I get the response from the blog service as expected. However when querying from http://10.0.0.1/blog/ nginx redirects to http://10.0.0.1 and that's it.

What's wrong with this configuration? Why doesn't http://10.0.0.1/blog/ reverse proxy to the http://localhost:8080 blog service?

nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you sure that the redirect happens due to Nginx, not the proxy_pass target? I'm not sure that you need a trailing slash in your proxy_path (URI). [Check the doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: I killed the blog application so that there was nothing on 8080 and the redirects still happen.

Comment: What does `curl -I http://10.0.0.1/blog/` return?

Answer (score 0):

It was chrome caching an old response from nginx for http://10.0.0.1/blog/. Clearing the browser cache and trying again gave the expected result.